How to sort groups with custom sequence?
Currently the response that is being sent back to client side looks like this:
[
  {
    "categoryName": "Orders",
    "categoryItems": [
      {
        "group": "Group B",
        "groupSettings": [
          {
            "settingName": "Group b description"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "group": "Group C",
        "groupSettings": [
          {
            "settingName": "Group c description"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "group": "Group A",
        "groupSettings": [
          {
            "settingName": "Group a description"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "categoryName": "Notifications",
    "categoryItems": [
      {
        "group": "",
        "groupSettings": [
          {
            "settingName": "Notification setting"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "categoryName": "Personalisation",
    "categoryItems": [
      {
        "group": "",
        "groupSettings": [
          {
            "settingName": "Personalisation setting"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]

However, the expected layout is:
[
  {
    "categoryName": "Personalisation",
    "categoryItems": [
      {
        "group": "",
        "groupSettings": [
          {
            "settingName": "Personalisation setting"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "categoryName": "Notifications",
    "categoryItems": [
      {
        "group": "",
        "groupSettings": [
          {
            "settingName": "Notification setting"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "categoryName": "Orders",
    "categoryItems": [
      {
        "group": "Group A",
        "groupSettings": [
          {
            "settingName": "Group a description"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "group": "Group b",
        "groupSettings": [
          {
            "settingName": "Group b description"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "group": "Group c",
        "groupSettings": [
          {
            "settingName": "Group c description"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]

How do I sort the categoryName to match the order that I expected? I am thinking about matching the sort order to an array of object with categoryName and sequence
properties, but I am stuck at the code.
My current code is as below:
const groupedData = _.chain(allData)
      .groupBy('sectionName')
      .map((allData, sectionName) => ({
        categoryName: sectionName,
        categorySettings: _.chain(allData)
          .groupBy('group')
          .map((groupSettings, group) => ({
            group: group,
            groupSettings: _.chain(groupSettings)
              .sortBy('ordering')
              .groupBy('title')
              .map((titleSettings, title) => ({
                settingName: title,
                settingDescription: titleSettings[0].description,
                settingInputs: _.map(titleSettings, ({name, value, inputSetting}) => ({
                  inputName: name,
                  inputValue: value,
                  inputConfig: inputSetting,
                })),
              }))
              .value(),
          }))
          .value(),
      }))
      .value();


This question is similar to: Sort a JavaScript array based on another array. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You can create a mapping of categoryName and groupOrder to the required order i.e. index and then use that mapping to sort the data.
I have reused your code. Considering you are using TS, i have made it typesafe too:
//define an enum for checking during compile time
enum CategoryName {
  Personalisation = "Personalisation",
  Notifications = "Notifications",
  Orders = "Orders",
}

//sort order for both categoryName and group
const categoryOrder: Record<CategoryName, number> = {
  [CategoryName.Personalisation]: 0,
  [CategoryName.Notifications]: 1,
  [CategoryName.Orders]: 2,
};

//this will give you control on the group order, but if you want to generalize the sorting in alphabetical order, check the next solution
const groupOrder: Record<string, number> = {
  "Group A": 0,
  "Group B": 1,
  "Group C": 2,
};

const sortedGroupedData = _.chain(allData)
  .groupBy('sectionName')
  .map((allData, sectionName) => ({
    categoryName: sectionName as CategoryName,
    categoryItems: _.chain(allData)
      .groupBy('group')
      .map((groupSettings, group) => ({
        group: group,
        groupSettings: _.chain(groupSettings)
          .sortBy('ordering')
          .map(({ name }) => ({
            settingName: name,
          }))
          .value(),
      }))
      .sortBy(groupItem => groupOrder[groupItem.group])
      .value(),
  }))
  .sortBy(item => categoryOrder[item.categoryName])
  .value();

console.log(sortedGroupedData);

(or) if you want to sort the groups generally in alphabetical order
enum CategoryName {
  Personalisation = "Personalisation",
  Notifications = "Notifications",
  Orders = "Orders",
}

//define the sort order for categoryName
const categoryOrder: Record<CategoryName, number> = {
  [CategoryName.Personalisation]: 0,
  [CategoryName.Notifications]: 1,
  [CategoryName.Orders]: 2,
};

const sortedGroupedData = _.chain(allData)
  .groupBy('sectionName')
  .map((allData, sectionName) => ({
    categoryName: sectionName as CategoryName,
    categoryItems: _.chain(allData)
      .groupBy('group')
      .map((groupSettings, group) => ({
        group: group,
        groupSettings: _.chain(groupSettings)
          .sortBy('ordering')
          .map(({ name }) => ({
            settingName: name,
          }))
          .value(),
      }))
      .sortBy(groupItem => groupItem.group.toLowerCase()) //groups sorted alphabetically
      .value(),
  }))
  .sortBy(item => categoryOrder[item.categoryName])
  .value();

console.log(sortedGroupedData);

You can use whichever you suits your purpose better

I have edited my question to include nested object as well. I am stuck on the sorting inside the nested object.

in that case you would have to fist order by categories and then by groups, let me update the answer

updated........

it finally works.. thank you so much for clearing my headache..
